# Can free objects be described in these terms, or am I kidding myself?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $T$ is an equational theory, and let $T[X]$ denote the theory obtained by adjoining a set of constant symbols $X$ to the theory $T$, subject to no axioms.

Is the free $T$-algebra generated by $X$ isomorphic to (the forgetful image of) the initial object in the category of $T[X]$-algebras? Can free objects be described in these terms, or am I kidding myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. A $T[X]$-algebra is the same as a $T$-algebra $A$ equipped with a map $X \to |A|$ to the underlying set. Morphisms are commutative diagrams in the obvious sense. Now the definition of a free $T$-algebra on $X$ coincides with an initial object in the category of $T[X]$-algebras.

More generally, let $F : C \to D$ be left adjoint to $G : D \to C$. If $X \in C$, then $F(X)$ together with the unit $X \to G(F(X))$ is an initial object in $X \downarrow G$.